# Black background on creating a image from imagegrabscreen() with php

Tags: php, function

I am using the code

```
<?php
echo 'Hi';
$im = imagegrabscreen();
imagejpeg($im, "myscreenshot.jpg");
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

This is creating a image myscreenshot.jpg with black background.But Iam expecting a jpeg image with white background and hi written on it

Comment: what do you get if you put print_r($im);die(); after imagegrabscreen();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem see ans you are getting this error because Apache is not allowed to interact with your desktop (Note)

Solution 1 : Apache Permission :

- Run the command `services.msc` as Admin.
- Find the Apache service in the list, right click and select Properties
- Click the Log On tab
- Change the service to use a local system account if it isn't already
- Check the box that says `Allow this service to interact with the desktop`.
- Restart the Apache service.

Solution 2 :  us using ["boxcutter"](http://keepnote.org/boxcutter/)

```
 $exec = exec('boxcutter -f image.png');
```

Solution 3 : Using COM  seee ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabwindow.php )

```
$browser = new COM("InternetExplorer.Application");
$handle = $browser->HWND;
$browser->Visible = true;
$browser->Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com"); // path to your URL 

/* Still working? */
while ($browser->Busy) {
    com_message_pump(4000);
}
$im = imagegrabwindow($handle, 0);
$browser->Quit();
imagepng($im, "myscreenshot.jpg");
imagedestroy($im);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Then its not installed as a service ... that is why i gave you other options .....

Answer (score 0):

For this to work your Apache service must be set to 'Allow service to interact with desktop' otherwise you will just get a blank image.

To fix this on Windows, right-click My Computer, select Manage/Services and Applications/Services - find the apache service (like Apache2) and right-click, select Properties - choose the Log on tab and check the 'Allow service to interact with desktop' checkbox. Restart Apache.